# Where I can get official Google ads API in node.js?

Tags: node.js, google-ads-api

I have to implement Google ads API's in node.js. But I didn't found official API on google documentation https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/start. Any help highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no official API for nodejs. However, there is an thrid-party library you can try: https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-ad-manager-api